# Откуда берутся значения в генераторе

Tags: php, генераторы

Читаю "PHP 7 в подлиннике" Д.Котерова. B главе 12 про генераторы упоминают. Решил попробовать комбинирование генераторов и не могу понять откуда берется итоговое  значение при выводе на экран.

```
<?php  
//функция генератор
function gen($arr, $func){
    foreach($arr as $v){

        yield $func($v);
    }
}


$arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

//получаем только четные числа
$select = gen($arr,function($i){ if($i % 2 === 0) return $i; });

//foreach($select as $v) {
//  echo "$v ";    // 2 4 6 - все верно
//} 

//возвращаем квадрат чисел массива, в качестве массива передаем результат работы генератора $select
$collect = gen($select,function($s){ return $s * $s; });

foreach($collect as $v) {
    echo "$v ";    // 0 4 0 16 0 36 - ОТКУДА БЕРУТСЯ НУЛИ?
} 


 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда функция с `if($i % 2)` не возвращает число, она возвращает null. Дальше понятно.

Ну а так-то, лютый, дичайший говнокод. И эти люди пишут учебники.